# Variable "app" does not exist with Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to get the URL of my page with Twig.
So I wrote this in my index.html.twig:
`{{ app.request.attributes.get("_route") }}`

I'm getting this Symfony exception:

> Variable "app" does not in exist in "AcmeFoo..."

Comment: Are you using Symfony Framework Standard edition or Silex or just Twig? Which version?

Comment: @hacfi I'm using Symfony Framework Standard Edition version 2.6

Comment: Your exact code is working here, can you add some context?

Comment: @Moritz here my controller : http://pastebin.com/1EKqvV5M and here my view : http://pastebin.com/A3ufJmJq

Comment: @mathieu_b sorry, still cant reproduce it. Since your code is pretty much vanilla, i would think thats something with the configuration or the cache is gone wrong. Have you tried clearing the symfony cache?

`php app/console cache:clear`

Comment: I solved the problem but I don't know how. I tried to get the url in another view and by another controller and it's work.
Very strange, but problem solved ! Thanks

Comment: @mathieu_b Very odd. Did you make any special modifications to your config(.yml) or Twig? Are you using any Twig Extensions?

Comment: @hacfi Nope, I use a vanilla version of Symfony. I rewrote (I wrote the same thing) my controller and it's work, It's very weird  (and it's very annoying...)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and sometimes in addition to clearing the cache, it was necessary to rebuild the bootstrap cache. I created a little shell script (cache.sh) like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /yoursymfonyrootfolder
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod

#path depends on symfony version
php ./vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

Just place that file in your symfony root folder and execute it with ./cache.sh